# how to set function after the first slide (using previous button) in jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I found this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/28/ which sets an alert after the last slide when using the next button. Is there any way to set the same alert after the first slide when going backwards using the previous button?

Here's the code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
   fx: 'scrollHorz',
   nowrap: false,
   timeout: 0,
   fx: 'scrollHorz',
   next: '.next',
   prev: '.prev',
   onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex) { 
      if(isNext && zeroBasedSlideIndex == 0)
      {
        alert('The slideshow has ended.');
      }
   }
});
```

I'm trying to link a giant slideshow between different URLs, so if I could go to one page after the last slide (on next) and go to another page after the first slide (on previous), that'd be great.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/35/ adapt it to your needs

Comment: perfect! thanks. just wasn't sure of the syntax.